# Importing a table from one Excel workbook into another workbook sheet

Tags: excel, import, vba

I currently have two workbooks open. Workbook A (for example), has a table inside of it that I want to import into an existing workbook, Workbook B.  I want to import this table into the same sheet I am currently using in workbook B.  Looked around a lot and cannot seem to topple the answer. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  T

Comment: did you try to record a macro with the macro recorder and use it?

Comment: It is going to differ every time I do it so I can not use the recorder

Comment: yes you can, when you have the macro recorded then you need "only" to modify the code to ask the user the name of the file from which you have to copy the table. I know that it's a bit complicated, but if you look into this solution and show some of your tries here, you will get much more help on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will prompt the user to select the range in the other book to copy and then copy it to the current sheet in cell B2.  You can also prompt the user to select the destination, just copy the other inputbox code and modify it to suit your needs.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Set wk = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks("Book1.xls")

    wkb.Activate

    On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "Please select a range with your Mouse to be copied.", _
                    Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        If rRange Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

    rRange.Select
    Selection.Copy

    wk.Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: It is giving me the run time error, subscript out of range. Not sure why because I am entering the correct .xls that i want to use

Comment: Currently the code is assuming that the book is already opened.  Does it work if you open it first and then run it?  Also, make sure that the file extension is correct. ie. .xls or .xlsx or .xlsm